# Error pushing gem. RubyGems.org cannot process this gem. The metadata is invalid. Unknown alias: id001

Tags: ruby, rubygems

We have version 0.1 of our gem published in rubygems, but can't push a new version of it. Rubygems always returns:

```
ricardofiel$ gem push -V invoicexpress-0.1.2.gem
GET http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
200 OK
Pushing gem to https://rubygems.org...
POST https://rubygems.org/api/v1/gems
422 Unprocessable Entity
RubyGems.org cannot process this gem.
The metadata is invalid.
Unknown alias: id001
```

Full source of .gem file is below. Any ideas? Thanks

```
lib = File.expand_path("../lib", __FILE__)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(lib)
require 'invoicexpress/version'

Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  spec.add_development_dependency 'bundler', '~> 1.0'

  spec.add_dependency 'faraday', '~> 0.8'
  spec.add_dependency 'faraday_middleware', '~> 0.9'
  spec.add_dependency 'happymapper', '~> 0.4'

  spec.authors = ["Think Orange"]
  spec.description = %q{Simple wrapper for invoicexpress.com API}
  spec.email = ['info@thinkorange.pt']
  spec.files = %w(CHANGELOG.md README.md Rakefile invoicexpress.gemspec)
  spec.files += Dir.glob("lib/**/*.rb")
  spec.files += Dir.glob("spec/**/*")
  spec.homepage = "http://invoicexpress.com"
  spec.licenses = ['MIT']
  spec.name = 'invoicexpress'
  spec.require_paths = ['lib']
  spec.required_rubygems_version = '>= 1.3.6'
  spec.summary = spec.description
  spec.test_files = Dir.glob("spec/**/*")
  spec.version = Invoicexpress::VERSION
end
```

https://github.com/weareswat/invoicexpress-gem

https://rubygems.org/gems/invoicexpress

Comment: Same problem here. There was more than 4 months that I don't upload a gem, but its strange that there is only your comment about this problem in google.

Comment: Is there any way you can send me this .gem file, so I can debug this locally?

Comment: @ArthurNeves there you go. thanks! https://www.dropbox.com/s/k5a9xfcaxqhpwe7/invoicexpress-0.1.2.gem?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Problem

RubyGems.org is now using a more modern version of YAML parser, which is more secure and has more features.
This parser is more strict to old versions of YAML, and as far as I can tell you are using a older one, because you are using an older rubygem client version:

(from your .gem file)
`rubygems_version: 1.6.2`

#### Solution

Upgrade rubygem client:
`gem update --system`

**EDIT**

We fixed rubygems.org, https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems.org/pull/894 , so this should work again.

thanks

Comment: Updated, but still having the same issue. gem -v outputs 2.4.6. Added to https://www.dropbox.com/s/k5a9xfcaxqhpwe7/invoicexpress-0.1.2.gem?dl=0